# Power BI: Filter based on SUM

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a horizontal bar visual where I’ve plotted the users with the highest sales.

It is "user name" vs "SUM(sales)" (user names and sales are in two different tables).

I’ve also used a filter as I only want to see users with SUM(sales)>1000€.

Now, on this page I want to put other visuals so that I can see information about this group of users, such as:

- How many users are there?
- What's the average age?
- How many men and women?
  and so on...

However, if I use a page level filter on sales, I can only filter a single sale value and not the sum for the user.

How can I filter the page based on a user’s total sales?

Comment: Seems to me logic that when you use page level filters, you get this bahavior. You need a filter on your visual.. If you want our help you need to be more explicit on what you try to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a **calculated column** for a user’s total sales in your username table and then filter based on that.

```
Total Sales = CALCULATE(SUM(Table2[sales]))
```

There’re also solutions utilizing GROUP BY if you prefer that.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I had this idea but I was hoping there could be another option only using visuals.
But thanks